# How to display products from database without table?

Tags: php, html

I currently have a table in my lamp database which I would like to display products. However I have displayed the products, but the page looks un-professional. How to make the page more professional? I don't want to display the products in a table.

I have posted my code below:

```html
<?php
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","sam","");
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
mysql_select_db("products", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Products_table WHERE catid IN (1,2,7,8)"); 

echo "<table border='1'>
 <tr>
 
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>Image</th>
 <th>Description</th>
 <th>Contact Renter</th>
 <th>Rent price</th>
 </tr>";


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['productname'] . "</td>";

 
   echo "<td><img src='./images/products/".$row['productimage']."' width='150' height='100' alt=''></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['productdescription'] . "</td>"; 
   echo "<td>" . $row['rentersdetails'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['rentprice'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
echo <<<"buttons"
  <td>
     <input class="button_normal" type="button" value="Google Renter" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.co.uk/')"/>; 
     <input class="button_normal" type="button" value="Yahoo" onclick="window.open('https://www.yahoo.co.uk')"/>
  </td>    
buttons;
   }
 echo "</table>";
 mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

Comment: You have complete control over how the data is presented. If you don't want to use a table, then don't. If you need help formatting it some other way, please describe what you hope to see and maybe we can tell you how to achieve it.

Comment: google: 'html table styling' or lookup something like Boostrap, because in web from unprofessional to professional is a long way

Comment: I want to remove the table and use some other form which will make the page look more professional or something.

Comment: Did you know that you can fully style a table with css like wahtever you want ??

Comment: How do I style the table using css, however I have two columns which I don't want to include the table for as these are buttons, which are currently in the table. I need to remove both of the buttons from the table.

Comment: I don't want to include the table for as these are buttons, which are currently in the table. I need to remove both of the buttons from the table  --- has nothing to do with your question. currently i thing your are maybe loading 'html' from your DATABASE-Table or where do the buttons came from ?

Comment: I have two buttons which I have now updated in my code.

Comment: /*echo <<< ... buttons;*/ comment them out

Comment: I need the buttons so if i comment them out then users will not be able to select any of the buttons if they are commented out.

Comment: Could anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the results in a variable:

```
<?php
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","sam","");
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
mysql_select_db("products", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Products_table WHERE catid IN (1,2,7,8)"); 

$results = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
     $results[] = $row;
}

 mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

and call your $results array like so:

`$results[0]['value']`

or in a foreach

```
foreach($results as $row => $value) {
    //display your data however you like
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do You mean 'unprofessional'? You can style Your table with css.
Or create grid with div's with block or inline-block display property.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using BootStrap CSS? I know you don't want to use tables to display the data but adding BootStrap or other CSS templates will make it look less "ugly" and less like a "table". Other than that, perhaps use lists? or other data structures?

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

Adding it should be pretty simple, you can even use the links from the CDN that they provide below. Hope this helps!

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just dont want the information in table format as it looks un professioal, I would like the data to be in some other from other than a table.

Comment: Well then I guess you're pretty much left to style it on your own using <div>'s and however you'd like to position them. Might I suggest some JQuery?? It looks to me you are trying to display products for rent. Perhaps you can use lists <li> and have your users click on each one and have JQuery pop up a box with details??

Answer (score 0):

try to use PDO and use fetchAll() :
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$first = '';$rows=array();    
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 if(!$first){
  $first="<tr><th>".implode('</th><th>',array_keys($row)).'</th></tr>';
 }
 $rows[]="<tr><td>".implode('</td><td>',$row).'</td></tr>';
}
$table = "<table class="table">$first".implode("\n",$rows)."</table>";
```

For Simple Product HTML http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-single-product-page/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","sam","");
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("products", $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Products_table WHERE catid IN (1,2,7,8)");
?>

<table style="border:1px solid;">
    <tr style="background:#000;color:#fff;">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Contact Renter</th>
        <th>Rent price</th>
    </tr>

<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['productname'];?></td>
        <td><img src='./images/products/<?php echo $row["productimage"];?>' width='150' height='100' alt=''></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['productdescription'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['rentersdetails'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['rentprice'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
    mysql_close($con);
?>

</table>

apply this code.... remember one thing more don't echo html tags. Due to echo/print html tags in php code it will slow your page speed. Your page will take more time for load.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can post your data to a responsive table made of Div tags. It looks like a table in large screens and changes to individual elements in smaller mobiles:

```
<div id = "" class="csstable u-full-width">
<div class="cssthead">
<div class="cssth">ccid</div>
<div class="cssth">administration_title</div>
<div class="cssth">author_id</div>
<div class="cssth">date_created</div>
</div>

<div class="csstbody">
<div class="csstr">
<div class="csslabel">ccid</div><div class="csstd">ccid-5528b9495c6864.97942127</div>
<div class="cssnlbr"></div>
<div class="csslabel">administration_title</div><div class="csstd">ccid-5528b9495c6864.97942127-title</div>
<div class="cssnlbr"></div>
<div class="csslabel">author_id</div><div class="csstd">1</div>
<div class="cssnlbr"></div>
<div class="csslabel">date_created</div><div class="csstd">2015-04-11 08:03:53</div>
<div class="cssnlbr"></div>
</div>

<div class="csstr">
<div class="csslabel">ccid</div><div class="csstd">ccid-5528b992dacfc7.34608410</div>
<div class="cssnlbr"></div>
<div class="csslabel">administration_title</div><div class="csstd">ccid-5528b992dacfc7.34608410-title</div>
<div class="cssnlbr"></div>
<div class="csslabel">author_id</div><div class="csstd">1</div>
<div class="cssnlbr"></div>
<div class="csslabel">date_created</div><div class="csstd">2015-04-11 08:05:06</div>
<div class="cssnlbr"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Larger than tablet */
@media (min-width: 750px)
{   /* border collapse is required for any borders to appear */
.csstable { display: table; border-collapse: collapse; }
.csstr { display: table-row }
.cssthead { display: table-header-group; border-bottom: 2px solid #eaeaea; }
.csstbody { display: table-row-group }
.csstfoot { display: table-footer-group }
.csscol { display: table-column }
.csscolgroup { display: table-column-group }
.csstd  { display: table-cell; padding: 4px; }
.cssth { display: table-cell; font-weight: 600; padding: 0 0 0 4px; }
.csscaption { display: table-caption }
.csslabel{ display: none; }
.cssnlbr{ display: none; }
.csstr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
}

/* smaller than tablet */
@media (max-width: 750px)
{   /* border collapse is required for any borders to appear */
.csstable { display: block }
.csstr { display: block; border: 1px solid #e1e1e1; padding: 4px; margin-bottom: 4px;}
.cssthead { display: none }
.csstbody { display: block }
.csstfoot { display: none }
.csscol { display: block }
.csscolgroup { display: block }
.csstd  { display: inline-block }
.cssth { display: none; font-weight: 600;  }
.csscaption { display: table-caption }
.csslabel{ display: inline-block; font-weight: 600; padding-right:6px; }
.cssnlbr{ display: block; height: 3px;}
}
```

I don't have time to find and use a code parsing site. But you can see how it works here on [my framework development site.](http://cck.fhqk.com/?blog/blog_list)